# How to group by a key and get count of items in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

Consider the following simple graph:

[image]

I want to find the number of movies that each director has worked on.

In Cypher, I would do the following:

```
MATCH (p:Person) -[:DIRECTED]-> (m:Movie) return p.name, count(m)
```

I am new to Gremlin and struggling to produce a working query to get this done. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gremlin it will be a query such as

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Person').
  group().
    by('name').
    by(out('DIRECTED').count())
```